# PHP - Mysql adding values in single column if value in other columns are duplicates

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having an issue figuring a part out while writing the below code. I am pulling data from 2 different tables and using an inner join to link a column together, which is working fine. When getting data from the `headkey` column, the there can be multiple rows with the same "key" to identify an order and then I need to be looking at the `Delivery` column to see if the order has the value 1 or -1. I need to be able to add the 1 AND the -1 together, so if an order has a 1 AND a -1 that would equal to 0 which means that the delivery was cancelled. But if the order had 1 + (-1) + 1, well that will equal a 1. In that case, that is a delivery. Is it possible to add values in the `delivery` column if the values in the `headkey` column match? I was thinking using multidimentional arrays, but I dont fully understand them to be able to implement them.

```
<?php

$TransactionSql = "
SELECT apcshead.Key
, apcshead.DateInvoiced
, apcshead.InvNum
, apcsitem.Headkey
, apcsitem.ItemID
, apcsitem.Quantity
, apcshead.CustomerCode
, customers.BillTo1
, customers.BillTo2
, customers.City
, customers.PostCode
FROM customers 
INNER JOIN (apcshead INNER JOIN apcsitem ON apcshead.Key = apcsitem.Headkey)
ON customers.CustomerCode = apcshead.CustomerCode";


$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$TransactionSql);
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) 
 {
$Key = odbc_result($rs,"Key");  
$DateInvoiced = odbc_result($rs,"DateInvoiced");
$InvNum = odbc_result($rs,"InvNum");
$Headkey = odbc_result($rs,"Headkey");
$ItemID = odbc_result($rs,"ItemID");
$Quantity = odbc_result($rs,"Quantity");
$CustomerCode = odbc_result($rs,"CustomerCode");

$DateInvoiced = new DateTime($DateInvoiced);
$DateInvoiced_date = $DateInvoiced->format('m-d-Y');

$DeliverySql = "SELECT Quantity, HeadKey FROM apcsitem WHERE HeadKey=20008";

if ($DateInvoiced_date == $Today)
{
    if ($ItemID == 'Delivery' xor $ItemID == 'DeliveryCharge')
    {
    echo '
        <td class="td" valign="top">' . $Key . '</td>
        <td class="td" valign="top">' . $DateInvoiced_date . '</td>
        <td class="td" valign="top">' . $InvNum . '</td>
        <td class="td" valign="top">' . $Headkey . '</td>
        <td class="td" valign="top">' . $ItemID . '</td>
        <td class="td" valign="top">' . $Quantity . '</td>
        <td class="td" valign="top">' . $CustomerCode . '</td>
        </tr> ';
    }
}

}

?>
```

Here is a snapshot of the table.
[image: Table Example]

**Stripped Down Version**

```
$TransactionSql = "SELECT * FROM apcsitem";

$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$TransactionSql);
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) 
{
$Key = odbc_result($rs,"HeadKey");  
$ItemID = odbc_result($rs,"ItemID");
$Quantity = odbc_result($rs,"Quantity");

if ($ItemID == 'Delivery' xor $ItemID == 'DeliveryCharge')
{
 echo '
        <td class="td" valign="top">' . $Key . '</td>
        <td class="td" valign="top">' . $ItemID . '</td>
        <td class="td" valign="top">' . $Quantity . '</td>
        </tr> ';
    }
}
```

Below is an example of a real transaction that was done by an confused employee :)

[image]

So basically what I need to be able to do is if second column contains delivery or deliveryCharge to filter them out. Then if any of them have a duplicate HeadKey (value in first column) to add the values of the last column for only the filtered ones. AKA, the ones with the same HeadKey. In the image above they have Delivery and DeliveryCharge. They added them and cancelled them. If you add the last column based on the group (Delivery) the result is 0 and if you add the last column with the group (DeliveryCharge) you will also get 0. Which in fact means after all that, there was no delivery!

Comment: All rows in your example are 'delivery' or 'delivery charge'. So all rows will filtered out. So that's why you won't get anything. The pluses and minuses are irrelevant - I feel that you're making this problem much more complicated than it needs to be. If I were you, I'd start again, with the minimum amount of code required to adequately illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to optimize by changing your business logic into a mathematical sum.

Something like:

```
$delivered = $order["ready"] === "yes" && $order["charged"] === "yes";
$cancelled = $order["ready"] === "yes" && $order["cancelled"] === "yes";
```

is much more clear.

I would consider using `ENUM` for true/false or yes/no fields. It's *much* more understandable. You can have as many states as you want so you don't need the wonky `-1`.

Comment: Hi - I wish I had control over that. The data with -1 and 1 are actually being dumped from the pos system itself and I can't change the way it works...

Answer (score 0):

Can we start with this...

```
SELECT h.Key
     , h.DateInvoiced
     , h.InvNum
     , i.Headkey
     , i.ItemID
     , i.Quantity
     , h.CustomerCode
     , c.BillTo1
     , c.BillTo2
     , c.City
     , c.PostCode 
  FROM customers c
  JOIN apcshead h
    ON h.CustomerCode = c.CustomerCode 
  JOIN apcsitem i
    ON i.Headkey = h.Key;
```

Comment: Not sure if I am understanding the above SQL statement. Are you suggesting that I modify it for the sake of the question and better flow?

Comment: Done :) - Also added a picture of the table I am echoing out

Comment: Nearly, but this parenthetical join is confusing :-(

Comment: Let me spin up an example without the join at all

Comment: I went ahead and added a stripped down version with another picture and a little bit more explaining based on the image